# Capture image of 3D Object Python

Tags: python, 3d, python-3.4

How would I go about getting an image of a 3D object (.stl or .obj) in python? I need to output .jpg's or .png's of the object at different rotations. It also needs to run headless.

Comment: Hi, You got any solution for getting output as .jpg using python?. Can you please help me, im also stuck on this. anyone help me related to this question

Comment: Here's something I threw together which should work for you with tweaking on a linux distro: https://github.com/MaxLFarrell/Headless3DCapture if you're looking for something on Windows, unfortunately, I don't know of a headless windows system like xvfb that would work for this, but if you're on windows 10 you can always use the ubuntu subsytem!

Comment: Thank you so much, i had an issue on this, i can't able to take screenshot of 3d face object. After out test.png, it shows as blank image

Comment: can you please help me out!

Comment: I'm sorry you will need to change the lines marked glrotatef in the script, you should open up the model in a different 3d program first to see what coordinates you need the object to be at. If you have any other questions please ask on the github page as it seems the moderators are displeased with the answers im giving